# how to parse base64 string column to plain text to populate XRRichText?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, devexpress, xtrareport

what I am trying to achieve is to show in the xtrareport a plain text from a base64 string (or a byte array of an XML), this is the data that's saved to the db:

```
byte[] fileContents = System.Convert.FromBase64String(obj.column);
obj.rtf_handler = fileContents;
```

and what I have achieved instead is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s94n0.png) long string of un-parsed(?) rtf content.
So how do you parse the 64base string from `obj.rtf_handler` to a plain text in xtrareport?

Comment: Posting the data as link to an image on an external site makes it difficult for readers to see it and experiment with the data. Can you [edit] your quesdtion and provide (part of) the data as text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I have found that I needed to pass the value of the data as a string and then to base64 string and pass it to Memory Stream to get the file.
Source: https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t678278/xrrichtext-and-openxml

Answer (score 0):

In DevExpress you can [load RTF from a datasource](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRRichText#load-from-a-data-source) but it seems that your base64 string representing a file and not its `RTF` content (which is similar to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format#Code_syntax)).

A possible solution could be save your file using [`FileStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=net-6.0) class and then read its `RTF` content using [`File.ReadAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Yes, after some research, I decided to use MemoryStream as provided in an answer of this [ticket](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t678278/xrrichtext-and-openxml)